# Recursion in html like data structure using clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, hiccup

I have been thinking about this problem, but I can't figure out the steps to build my function:

I have an hiccup like html data as input, this structure is composed by html and custom elements, example:

format: [**tag-name** options & **body**]

```
[:a {} []] ;; simple
[:a {} [[:span {} []]]] ;; nested component
[:other {} []] ;; custom component at tag-name
[:a {} [[:other {} []]]] ;; custom component at body
```

Every time the structure have a custom element, I should render(replace) it by the html representation that is in the `database`, the custom element may be present at **tag-name** or **body**:

```
(def example
  [:div {} [[:a {} []]
            [:custom {} []]]])

    (def database {
      :custom [[:a {} []
               [:div {} []]})

(def expected-result
  [:div {} [[:a {} []]
            [:a {} []]
            [:div {} []]]])
```

The problem was: How create a function that takes this data, look for the tag and body of the component, if there's a custom element replace it by the `database` element, after the replace it, look at it again, if there's new components do this steps again...

I already have a function(**custom-component?**) that takes a tag name and returns a boolean if is a custom element:

```
(custom-component? :a) ;; false
(custom-component? :test) ;; true
```

Thanks for any help, I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Reagent project](https://reagent-project.github.io/)?

Comment: @jmargolisvt I need output just html, at end will be all static html(this is the objective)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clojure has a special way of fullfilling this task - zippers: 
http://josf.info/blog/2014/03/28/clojure-zippers-structure-editing-with-your-mind/

here is a sketchy example of your question's solution (i've added one more component into your `database`, to show that replace also happens recursively in a newly added component):

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(def example
  [:div {} [[:custom2 {} []]
            [:a {} []]
            [:custom {} []]]])

(def database {:custom [[:a {} []]
                        [:div {} [[:custom2 {} [[:p {} []]]]]]]
               :custom2 [[:span {} [[:form {} []]]]]})

(defn replace-tags [html replaces]
  (loop [current (z/zipper
                  identity last
                  (fn [node items]
                    [(first node) (second node) (vec items)])
                  html)]
    (if (z/end? current)
      (z/root current)
      (if-let [r (-> current z/node first replaces)]
        (recur (z/remove (reduce z/insert-right current (reverse r))))
        (recur (z/next current))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (replace-tags example database)
[:div {} [[:span {} [[:form {} []]]] 
          [:a {} []] 
          [:a {} []] 
          [:div {} [[:span {} [[:form {} []]]]]]]]
```

but beware: it doesn't compute cycles inside your replacements, so if you have a circular dependency like this:

```
(def database {:custom [[:a {} []]
                        [:div {} [[:custom2 {} [[:p {} []]]]]]]
               :custom2 [[:span {} [[:custom {} []]]]]})
```

it would produce an infinite loop.

Comment: Great answer! It led me to refresh my knowledge on zippers :) One question though: as the input is Hiccup markup, it might have children "unpacked" in the element vector (e.g. `[:div "Child1" "Child2"]`). Shouldn't the `branch?` function instead of `identity` be `vector?` and `children` function instead of `last` be `(fn [[tag & xs]] (if (map? (first xs)) (next xs) xs))`?

Comment: Well, probably it should be that way. My answer only provides a solution for the "hiccup like" structure from the op's question, not all the valid hiccup syntax.  Obviously, one has to carefully think through all the variants for a production ready solution.